# Find all real triples $(x,y,z)$ such that: $x^2+1=2y,y^2+1=2z,z^2+1=2x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system

> Find all real triples $(x,y,z)$ such that: $x^2+1=2y,y^2+1=2z,z^2+1=2x$.

Can it be solved avoiding equations of orders higher than 2?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Adding all the equations, we get -

$$x^2+1+y^2+1+z^2+1=2x+2y+2z$$

$$x^2-2x+1+y^2-2y+1+z^2-2z+1=0$$

$$(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2+(z-1)^2=0$$

$$\implies x=y=z=1$$

Answer (score 1):

HINT: we get $$x,y,z\geq 0$$ eliminating $y,z$ from the given System we get
$$- \left( {x}^{6}+2\,{x}^{5}+7\,{x}^{4}+12\,{x}^{3}+31\,{x}^{2}+50\,x+
89 \right)  \left( x-1 \right) ^{2}
=0$$ therefore we obtain $$x=y=z=1$$
the plonomial above has only complex solutions

Comment: And how do you know $\left( {x}^{6}+2\,{x}^{5}+7\,{x}^{4}+12\,{x}^{3}+31\,{x}^{2}+50\,x+
89 \right)$ doesn't factor to give more solutions? Also the question specifically asked for solutions avoiding polynomials of degree greater than 2.

Comment: i'm sure this polynomial has only complex Solutions, there are several Theorem with the help of that we can pove this

Comment: Then write it in the answer

Comment: **Please**, prove that  $\left( {x}^{6}+2\,{x}^{5}+7\,{x}^{4}+12\,{x}^{3}+31\,{x}^{2}+50\,x+ 89 \right)$ does not factor.

Comment: see here https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E6%2B2*x%5E5%2B7*x%5E4%2B12*x%5E3%2B31*x%5E2%2B50*x%2B89%3D0

Comment: Dr Sonnhard is right: since $x\geq \frac12$,the polynomial with degree 6 is obviously greater than 0.